# Uploading Document to App_Data

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file

I've currently got some working code that will upload a document to the App_data file, however I need to be able to differentiate the files uploaded if they have the same name. I want to do this by modifying the file name like so: ID" "Filename

I've had a few attempts to include this in the object thats passed to the controller but I can't find it stored anywhere (I presume that it gets stripped out when being passed?).

Here is my current code:

```
var files = $('#txtUploadFile')[0].files;
if (files.length > 0) {
    if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
        var data = new FormData();
        for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
        }
        // data.uploadName = task.Id + " " + files[0].name; 

        // File.filename = Id + " " + file.filename;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../Document/UploadFiles/',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //data: {'id': (nextRef + 1), 'fileLocation': files[0].name }, // THIS DOESN'T WORK
            data: data, // THIS WORKS WITHOUT ANY OTHER VARIABLES
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                alert(log(err));
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
    }
}



[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFiles()//string id, string fileLocation)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
            if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                continue;
            var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
            if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // get a stream
                var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
                // and optionally write the file to disk
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));

                // Save the file
                hpf.SaveAs(path); 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return this.Json("Upload failed");
    }

    return this.Json("File uploaded successfully");
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a major flaw with your code. What happens when userA uploads a file named (say) Report.doc and userB later uploads a file also named Report.doc. To solve this and your current identified problem, you would need to check is an existing file exists in the directory with the same name, and if so give it a new name (e.g. append a suffix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html should be

```
<div><input type="file" name="UploadFile" id="fileupload" Class="fileupload"  />
</div>
```

your ajax call should be

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/MyController/UploadFiles?id=' + myID,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           data: data,
           success: function(result) {
               console.log(result);
           },
           error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4){

            });
```

//and your controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult UploadFiles(string id)  
 {
            // whatever you want to that id
 }
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

change from `url: '../Document/UploadFiles/',` to `url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles","YourController")`
and in your controller

```
public class YourController:Controller{
  [HttpPost]
   publiction ActionResult UploadFiles(){
        if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {              
          string path=Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
          Request.Files[0].SaveAs(path + fileName);
      return Json("File uploaded","text/json",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
      return Json("No File","text/json",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```